# Best data structure to store lots one bit data

Tags: data-structures

I want to store lots of data so that

1. they can be accessed by an index,
2. each data is just yes and no (so probably one bit is enough for each)

I am looking for the data structure which has the highest performance and occupy least space.

probably storing data in a flat memory, one bit per data is not a good choice on the other hand using different type of tree structures still use lots of memory (e.g. pointers in each node are required to make these tree even though each node has just one bit of data).

Does anyone have any Idea?

Comment: why the one bit per data in flat memory a bad idea?

Comment: How big is lots and how "dense" will your data be?

Comment: I would have to assume that as each bit indicates Yes or No, that all the bits would be used. In which case you could not got any better than a flat memory space.

Comment: one bit per data in flat memory is not good idea as searching could be very time consuming, e.g. you want to find the first data which is 'no' then you should traverse all memory region from beginning each time. if you have 500,000 bit packed in unsigned long array then you would compare 15625 times.

Comment: @amrzar: you didn't specify anything about search requirements in the question - you should probably add this. Also what is the expected size of the data set ?

Comment: I am writing Linux kernel module and trying to log module behaviour using these data (module traverse all memory trying to log some data for each page) so it is important to consume less memory and be light!

Comment: @Paul R: sorry for that. actually not sure but it could be something about 700,000 to 900,000!

Comment: @amrzar: OK - that's actually quite small - only 100 k bytes for a packed array. What are the search requirements ?

Comment: @Paul R: you are right, i always thought of hundreds thousand, seems frightening, but from other point of view its just ~100k not too much. for search i only want to find the first 'no' in this bitmap!

Comment: @amrzar: OK - well one further advantage of a linear packed data structure is that you can search for the first 0 bit quite quickly - you can just iterate through the array loading a 32 bit or 64 bit integer and comparing it with an all 1s value.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with using a single block of memory and either storing 1 bit per byte (easy indexing, but wastes 7 bits per byte) or packing the data (*slightly* trickier indexing, but more memory efficient) ?

Answer (score 2):

Well in Java the BitSet might be a good choice http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you should store them in an unsigned integer where you assign each value to a bit of the integer (flag).

Say you represent 3 values and they can be on or off. Then you assign the first to 1, the second to 2 and the third to 4. Your unsigned int can then be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7 depending on which values are on or off and you check the values using bitwise comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the language and how you define 'index'. If you mean that the index operator must work, then your language will need to be able to overload the index operator. If you don't mind using an index macro or function, you can access the nth element by dividing the given index by the number of bits in your type (say 8 for char, 32 for uint32_t and variants), then return the result of `arr[n / n_bits] & (1 << (n % n_bits))`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a Bloom Filter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

It performs very well and is space-efficient.  But make sure you read the fine print below ;-): Quote from the above wiki page.

> An empty Bloom filter is a bit array
>   of m bits, all set to 0. There must
>   also be k different hash functions
>   defined, each of which maps or hashes
>   some set element to one of the m array
>   positions with a uniform random
>   distribution. To add an element, feed
>   it to each of the k hash functions to
>   get k array positions. Set the bits at
>   all these positions to 1. To query for
>   an element (test whether it is in the
>   set), feed it to each of the k hash
>   functions to get k array positions. If
>   any of the bits at these positions are
>   0, the element is not in the set – if
>   it were, then all the bits would have
>   been set to 1 when it was inserted. If
>   all are 1, then either the element is
>   in the set, or the bits have been set
>   to 1 during the insertion of other
>   elements. The requirement of designing
>   k different independent hash functions
>   can be prohibitive for large k. For a
>   good hash function with a wide output,
>   there should be little if any
>   correlation between different
>   bit-fields of such a hash, so this
>   type of hash can be used to generate
>   multiple "different" hash functions by
>   slicing its output into multiple bit
>   fields. Alternatively, one can pass k
>   different initial values (such as 0,
>   1, ..., k − 1) to a hash function that
>   takes an initial value; or add (or
>   append) these values to the key. For
>   larger m and/or k, independence among
>   the hash functions can be relaxed with
>   negligible increase in false positive
>   rate (Dillinger & Manolios (2004a),
>   Kirsch & Mitzenmacher (2006)).
>   Specifically, Dillinger & Manolios
>   (2004b) show the effectiveness of
>   using enhanced double hashing or
>   triple hashing, variants of double
>   hashing, to derive the k indices using
>   simple arithmetic on two or three
>   indices computed with independent hash
>   functions. Removing an element from
>   this simple Bloom filter is
>   impossible. The element maps to k
>   bits, and although setting any one of
>   these k bits to zero suffices to
>   remove it, this has the side effect of
>   removing any other elements that map
>   onto that bit, and we have no way of
>   determining whether any such elements
>   have been added. Such removal would
>   introduce a possibility for false
>   negatives, which are not allowed.
>   One-time removal of an element from a
>   Bloom filter can be simulated by
>   having a second Bloom filter that
>   contains items that have been removed.
>   However, false positives in the second
>   filter become false negatives in the
>   composite filter, which are not
>   permitted. In this approach re-adding
>   a previously removed item is not
>   possible, as one would have to remove
>   it from the "removed" filter. However,
>   it is often the case that all the keys
>   are available but are expensive to
>   enumerate (for example, requiring many
>   disk reads). When the false positive
>   rate gets too high, the filter can be
>   regenerated; this should be a
>   relatively rare event.

Comment: I don't think '0' or '1' lend themselves to being hash keys. On the other hand if the answers were grouped up into chunks of 32 or 64  (with all zero's considered to be empty) then it might be quite efficient if the answers were mostly zero.

Comment: I was assuming that their is some kind of key being mapped to the 1 or 0.  I missed the part about accessing the bits by an index.  He could still use a bloom-filter but a bit-field or bit-array would be better when you only have an index.